# updating a value from relation using JPA CriteriaUpdate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api, jpa-2.1

I have a composition relation between two entities A & B (A is the owner), i need to update a field value in the owned entity "B" using the owner entity "A" as root using JPA CriteriaUpdate, i tried to set the value of the whole entity B like this :

```
criteriaUpdate.from(A.class).set("B",valueOfB);
```

but it doesn't work because it doesn't traverse through the relation,
Any suggestion on how should i do this please ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
// Create criteria builder
CriteriaBuilder cb = this.em.getCriteriaBuilder();

//In Criteria Update cant define Joins, use B as Root entity
CriteriaUpdate<B> cq = cb.createCriteriaUpdate(B.class);

Root rootB = cq.from(B.class);

//Set te value in entity B (access property by Metamodel)
cq.set(rootB.get(B_.propertie), **newValue**);

//Set te condition over Root.Join.property (access propery by Metamodel)
cq.where(cb.equals(rootB.get(B_.a).get(A_.property),**valueEqualsPropertyB**));

em.createQuery(cq).executeUpdate();
```

Be careful, Bulk update in criteria does not respect the sequence of instructions execution in the same transaction.